# Why isn't $\lim_{x\to 0} x\sin(1/x)$ equal to $1$?

Tags: limits

How $\lim_{x\to 0} x\sin(1/x)$ is not equal to $1$?
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}  x\sin(1/x)  = \lim_{x\to 0}  \frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}=1
$$
What did I do wrong? My book says the answer is $0$.

But I used $\lim (\sin x )/ x=1 $ (formula).

Comment: It is not the case that as $x\to 0$,  $\frac{1}{x}\to 0$. So you cannot use the fact that $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$.

Comment: Your reasoning can be used to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin(1/x)=0$, because as $x\to\infty$, $1/x\to 0$.

Comment: Sry but i am new to stack exchange.. I am unable to understand what u wrote,  it's in code with many $ characters. :(

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \sin(x)/x = 1$ but $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sin(x)/x$ need not be 0.  And indeed is not..

Comment: @user347573: Somehow then you are looking at the source code. Are you getting the dollar sign stuff also in answers, or only in comments?

Comment: Only in the comments.

Comment: Are you using a phone app?  Don't.  The phone app is one the biggest pieces of crap I've ever seen.  Go to a web page and read it.  Anyway... lim sin t/t depends on what t is tending to.  If t is tending to 0 them lim sin t/t = 1.  But as 1/t does *not* tend to zero; it tends to infinity lim sin 1/t/(1/t) will *not* tend to 1.

Comment: Yes i am using the phone app.I better switch to webpage.. Anyways, i understood what you said. Thanks :)

Comment: Think about the result you're using rather than just applying it blindly. The limit in the formula you use is as $x \to 0$, not $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

As $x$ approaches $0$, $\frac{1}{x}$ increases without bound. That is
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x} = \pm \infty
$$
(the $\pm$ depends on what side you approach $0$ from.)

Now $\sin$ of anything is always bounded between $-1$ and $1$. So, when you multiply this by something ($x$) that approaches $0$, the whole thing is going to approach $0$.

Your book probably tells you that
$$
\lim_{\color{red}{y\to 0}} \frac{\sin(y)}{y} = 1
$$

The limit you have is basically
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} = 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to think of it is $-1 \le \sin (1/x) \le 1$ so **IF** the $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\sin(1/x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} -x \le \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\sin(1/x) \le \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x$. so $0 \le \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\sin(1/x) \le 0$.

So $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\sin(1/x)= 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sin(x)}{x}=1$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{sin(x)}{x}\right|\leq \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{1}{x}\right|=0$$

Answer (score 0):

check this page for formatting help

[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

$\lim_\limits {x\to 0} x \sin \frac 1x = 0$

Why?

$-1\le \sin \frac 1x\le1\\
-x\le x\sin \frac 1x\le x$

And as $x$ goes to $0, x\sin \frac 1x$ goes to $0$ by the squeeze theorem.

What have you done?

$\lim_\limits {x\to 0} x \sin \frac 1x$

Suppose we replace $x$ with $\frac 1x$

$\lim_\limits {x\to 0} x \sin \frac 1x = \lim_\limits{x\to \infty} \dfrac {\sin x}{x}$

All well and good, but then you evaluated the limit on the right as it approached 0, and not as it approached infinity.